# Find location `reject` for unhandled exceptions

Tags: javascript, exception, promise

When registering an exception handler for unhandled exceptions, I wonder how one would find out where this was triggered (something like a stacktrace). Since the `reject()` happened asynchronously, I don't expect a full stacktrace, but at least getting some info on where `reject()` was called from would be great. `e.reason` doesn't gives some detail, but I'd love to see the actual location in the code that triggered the `reject()`. For instance to test this, imagine the hypothetical example of multiple `reject('oops')` in the code which are all unhandled. I'll be great to see their actual location in the exception handler.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PromiseRejectionEvent

```
window.onunhandledrejection = function(e) {
  console.log('where does this originate from?', e.reason, e);
}

new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    reject('foo');
   }, 2000);
});

new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    reject('foo');
  }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: `e.stacktrace`?

Comment: @Bergi that'll be lovely ;-)

Comment: I added a small example which demonstrates the issue.